# React-select is not send in the request payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using react-select with react-bootstrap, but it don't send the selected options in the select to the request payload, it only sends the first two inputs

I've tried lots of props as you can see in the code, but when I check the request payload it doesn't send the select

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import Select from 'react-select'

export default class CreateMembro extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {mem_nome: '', mem_data_nascimento: '', selectedOption: null, opcoes: []}

    this.handleFormInput = this.handleFormInput.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  getHostName() {
    return `http://${window.location.hostname}`
  }


  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get(`${this.getHostName()}/get-all-ministerios`).then((res) => {

      let response = []

      res.data.map(r => {
        r.value = r.min_nome
        r.label = r.min_descricao

        delete r.min_nome
        delete r.min_descricao
        delete r.min_id
        delete r.created_at
        delete r.updated_at
        response.push(r);
      })

      this.setState({ opcoes: response})
    })
  }

    handleChange(selectedOption) {
     this.setState({ selectedOption });
     console.log(selectedOption)
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const dataForm = {
      mem_nome : this.state.mem_nome,
      mem_data_nascimento : this.state.mem_data_nascimento
    }

    axios.post(`${this.getHostName()}/membros`, dataForm).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    }).catch((error)=>{
       console.log(error)
    })
  }

  handleFormInput(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    })

    console.log(event.target.id+'--'+event.target.value)
  }

    render() {
        return (
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col md={6}>
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>Nome do Membro</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control id="mem_nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome do Membro" onChange={value = handleFormInput(value)} />

                    <Form.Label>Data de Nascimento</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control id="mem_data_nascimento" type="date" placeholder="Data de Nascimento" onChange={value = handleFormInput(value)}/>

                    <Form.Label >Ministérios</Form.Label>


                      <Select
                        id="minid"
                        name="asdasd89NAMEEE"
                        ref="refsid"
                        inputId={"minresss"}
                        inputId="ministerios"
                        controlId="sdasd78gd"
                        isMulti={true}
                        labelKey="labelkeu"
                        isSearchable={true}
                        value={this.state.selectedOption}
                        onChange={value = handleChange(value)}
                        options={this.state.opcoes}
                        placeholder="Selecione o(s) ministério(s)">

                      </Select>



                  </Form.Group>
                  <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
                    Enviar
                  </Button>
                </Form>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

I expect that the select values goes into the request payload.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the same library like you so you can take a look at mine code

I think your code should be change to something like this

change from this

```
 onChange={value = handleChange(value)}
```

to this

```
onChange={value => handleChange(value)}
```

and

```
const dataForm = {
      mem_nome : this.state.mem_nome,
      mem_data_nascimento : this.state.mem_data_nascimento,
      selectedOption: this.state.selectedOption  // you missing this
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't make the select goes into the request payload, I already have a function to handle submit, I'll update the code on question

Comment: Can you take a screen shot how your request payload is submit in the network tab ?

Comment: I Just did it :)

Comment: I see your code is  onChange={value = handleChange(value)} is this a typo ?

Comment: I changed to check if your answer could make it work, but it was: ```onChange={this.handleChange}```

Comment: Check my answer again you are missing selectedOption in your dataForm object :D

Comment: Thanks so much, that was the problem, I forgot to add the state on the dataForm :)